# Using super class methods that return a super class object - Java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I'm using the SimpleMatrix class from a jar file (EJML if you happen to know it).
I wanted to implement a new method to use with this class so decided to extend SimpleMatrix by creating the MyMatrix class.
However, when I use a static superclass method I am having problems. For example, If I try:

```
MyMatrix WL = MyMatrix.random64(layerDims[i], layerDims[i-1], min, max, rand);
```

I get a compilation error asking me to cast the result to MyMatrix. I believe this is because the method returns a SimpleMatrix object. If I try:

```
MyMatrix WL = (MyMatrix)(MyMatrix.random64(layerDims[i], layerDims[i-1], min, max, rand));
```

the program compiles but I then get a runtime error saying SimpleMatrix cannot be cast to MyMatrix. Why can't I cast it? MyMatrix simply extends the super class and has some constructors that call the super constructor and has one additional method.

I've got a workaround by creating a constructor in MyMatrix that takes a SimpleMatrix:

```
MyMatrix(SimpleMatrix simple)
{
   super(simple);
}
```

I can use this like so:

```
MyMatrix WL = new MyMatrix(MyMatrix.random64(layerDims[i], layerDims[i-1], min, max, rand));
```

This doesn't seem right though. Any suggestions how I should be handling this?

Comment: Hard to answer this without knowing what you're trying to achieve.  But the `random64` method makes a `SimpleMatrix` - it couldn't possibly make a `MyMatrix`, because it's not your method.  If you want a method that makes a `MyMatrix`, you'd need to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

For example, imagine you have Oranges and Apples, they are Fruits, right?
So, you treat them as Fruits.

**Now, imagine someone tells you:** This is a bag filled with Fruits, how can you know what kind of Fruits there are within the bag?  I mean, could be any Fruit.

**The same is happening at:**

`MyMatrix WL = MyMatrix.random64(layerDims[i], layerDims[i-1], min, max, rand);`

You're trying to guess or convert a Fruit into an Orange or Apple with no knowledge about what Fruit will be returned from `random64` method.  I mean, `random64` method could return pineapples.

In a nutshell, you can assign values to parent objects:

```
class Fruit {}

class Orange extends Fruit {}
```

**You can do the following:**

```
public Fruit getOrange() {
    return new Orange();
}

Fruit fruit = getOrange(); // Because you know Orange is a fruit.
```

**You can't do the following:**

```
Orange fruit = getOrange(); // Because you don't know what's the kind of fruit that will be returned by that method.
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Hi. I all ready understand the 'Student in a Person' but a Person is not necessarily a Student concept. But I thought a SimpleMatrix would also be a MyMatrix as it has no additional properties - just an additional method. Is inheritence useless to me in my scenario? All I want is an additional way to manipulate a SimpleMatrix. Ordinarily I'd put the new method in SimpleMartix but I don't think I can do that as I'm using a .jar file to access SimpleMatrix

Answer (score 0):

When calling static methods I recommend calling through the actual class they are defined in and not some subclass. For example `static random64` is defined in `SimpleMatrix` therefore I like to call it like this `SimpleMatrix.random64`

Also `random64` doesn't really know about `MyMatrix` and so it can't return a `MyMatrix`, only a `SimpleMatrix`.

Yes `MyMatrix` is a `SimpleMatrix` but a `SimpleMatrix` is not necessarily a `MyMatrix`. `random64` is returning an actual instance of the class `SimpleMatrix` which can't be cast to something lower in its class hierarchy.

You can do this:

```
Object o = (Object) "some string";
String s = (String) o; // because it is actually a String;
SimpleMatrix sm = (SimpleMatrix) new MyMatrix();
MyMatrix mm = (MyMatrix) sm; // because it is actually a MyMatrix
```

But not:

```
String s = (String) new Object(); // because it is not actually a String
MyMatrix m = (MyMatrix) new SimpleMatrix(); // because it is not actually a MyMatrix
```